# Sites page load times are extremely slow

Tags: javascript, wordpress, performance, elementor

I feel like I've tried everything to get my site to load faster but nothing seems to work, I've tried deferring Javascript, adding speed booster plugins, optimizing images, deleting plugins but I keep having a 17+ second page load time, does anyone have any ideas why this page could be loading so slow. outdoorsmanproperties.com. Thank you.

Comment: what is your site address ?

Comment: Your GMap overlays are causing the problem. Look at optimizing your GMap implementation.

Comment: your site speed is good ... you can optimize it by adding defer Attribute on All External Script Tags ... (some of them has not )